# fragmenttransaction over listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I've a listview in an activity and I want to open a fragment when an item is clicked. For that I used FrameLayout along with ListView but it causes overlapping of fragment class over the activity. Is there any way to remove this solution?

```css
Activity's Listview Item Click code:

 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

          

                DetailsView details = new DetailsView();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).add(R.id.frame, details).commit();
            }
        });
```

```html
activity layout:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `FragmentManager.Replace()` instead of `.add()`

Comment: Unfortunately, I've checked that both have the same result. @Alex.